# Not finding documents using golang's mgo with partial attributes

Tags: mongodb, go, attributes, partial, mgo

I'm trying to remove a bunch of documents that have a common attribute. This is what a document looks like:

```
{
    _id : {
        attr1 : 'foo',
        attr2 : 'bar'
    },
    attr3 : 'baz',
}
```

More than one document will have the same 'foo' value in the attr1 entry. I'm trying to remove all of those. For that I've got something similar to this:

```
type DocId struct {
    Attr1 string `bson:"attr1,omitempty"`
    Attr2 string `bson:"attr2,omitempty"`
}

type Doc struct {
    Id DocId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Attr3 string `bson:"attr3,omitempty"`
}


doc := Doc{
    Id : DocId{ Attr1 : 'foo' },
}

collection := session.DB("db").C("collection")
collection.Remove(doc)
```

The problem here is that I'm getting a `Not found` error in the remove call.
Can you see anything odd in the code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, one odd thing I see in the code is that it doesn't compile since `'foo'` results in a syntax error.

Comment: `Not found` may be the result of misspelling the name of the collection, or that you don't have any documents matching the criteria (e.g. you misspelled the attribute value, or you already deleted all that would match it). Can you confirm these are not the case?

Comment: @rightfold, as you can guess, this is just an example that you don't need to execute ;)

Comment: @icza, I already checked that. I'm querying the proper collection that do have matching criteria :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a consequence of the way MongoDB handles exact match and partial match. It can be quickly demonstrated using the mongo shell:

```
# Here are my documents
> db.docs.find()
{ "_id" : { "attr1" : "one", "attr2" : "two" }, "attr3" : "three" }
{ "_id" : { "attr1" : "four", "attr2" : "five" }, "attr3" : "six" }
{ "_id" : { "attr1" : "seven", "attr2" : "eight" }, "attr3" : "nine" }

# Test an exact match: it works fine
> db.docs.find({_id:{attr1:"one",attr2:"two"}})
{ "_id" : { "attr1" : "one", "attr2" : "two" }, "attr3" : "three" }

# Now let's remove attr2 from the query: nothing matches anymore,
# because MongoDB still thinks the query requires an exact match
> db.docs.find({_id:{attr1:"one"}})
... nothing returns ...

# And this is the proper way to query with a partial match: it now works fine.
> db.docs.find({"_id.attr1":"one"})
{ "_id" : { "attr1" : "one", "attr2" : "two" }, "attr3" : "three" }
```

You will find more information about this topic in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/).

In your Go program, I would suggest to use the following line:

```
err = collection.Remove(bson.M{"_id.attr1": "foo"})
```

Do not forget to test errors after each roundtrip to MongoDB.

Comment: Thank's a lot Didier. I know about the matching in mongo, that's how I was querying my documents on the console. The doubt was when I needed to write that behaviour using mgo.

Following what you're saying, I better start using the bson.M notation. Again, thank's a lot!